# How do I create a push button software reset for my 8051, AT89C51CC03 board micro-controller in C?

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I'm using an 8051 processor, AT89C51CC03 board, and coding C in Keil uVision.

I am trying to create a loop that checks if my push button is pressed and sends the program back to the start of the Main code.

The button is on an arbitrary pin i.e. P0_0.  If that pin goes `low = 0`, I want the program to jump back to the start of the code.

So far the only idea I've come up with is:

```
if (P0_0 == 0) {
  /* Reset */
} else {
  /* Body of the rest of the program */
}
```

I do not think this will satisfactorily accomplish my process as i will not look again at the reset button until after if runs the main body of my code, and if it encounters an error or a glitch, it may not get back to the reset.

Comment: Can you use `P3.2/INT0` or `P3.3/INT1` pins for your button instead? Or this board is finished, and no wiring is possible anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your application, but this may be just the first of several features where you will run into the same problem: how do I make the board do more than one thing at a time? There are many solutions, but a good one to start with would be the **superloop**. Michael Pont wrote a [decent introductory book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020179523X) to embedded C programming called *Embedded C*. There are some
 [notes from a lecture of his](http://www.le.ac.uk/eg/mjp9/pes1ohp_a4.pdf) on the subject available from his university [website](http://www.le.ac.uk/eg/mjp9/).

Boiled down, the flow of your program should look something like this:

```
initialization_stuff();
other_inititialization_stuff();

while(1)
{
    do_something();
    do_something_else();
    do_something_also();
} // do it again!
```

The `do_something()` functions are things that your application is actually intended to be doing. You might read some sensor, make a decision about it, and then act out the results of your decision. In almost all embedded applications, you then want to do it again. The program continues until someone unplugs it. You would check that button line (the `if` statement you wrote above, though without the `else`) within the `while(1)` loop.

This specific action you want to perform, a software reset, is not straightforward on your device. There is no register you can poke to induce a reset. It would be best if you just attached a button to RST that closed to ground. Then you don't even have to worry about programming it. But if you must do it in software, please look at [this documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka9013.html) from ARM. You can't just call `main()` again:

```
void reset (void)
{
    ((void (code *) (void)) 0x0000) ();
}
```

That won't reset your peripherals, but at least it will reinitialize your code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would connect your reset button between the `RST` pin and ground. The `RST` pin should be held high with a weak pull-up resistor, but when you press the button it will ground this pin and perform a hard reset.

If you can't rewire the button, you can just vector that pin to an interrupt. Then in your interrupt, you can trigger a soft reset of the processor.  This won't need to wait for the current function to finish.

As Phil points out above, you will most likely want a superloop at your top level anyway. It is not at all normal to invoke main yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to reset the processor (for the processors that don't have a Softreset() function) is to enable the watchdog and allow the watchdog timer to overflow thus obtaining the reset and jump to main function.

The watchdog timer should be set to overflow faster than the loop that will follow.

For example:

```
while( 1 )
{
    if (P0_0 == 0) 
    {
        /* Reset */
        Enable_Watchdog();    // WDT set to overflow between 5 - 10ms
        DelayMs(50);
    } 
    else  
    {
        /* Body of the rest of the program */
        DoSomething();
        DoSomethingElse();
        AndSoOn();
    }
}
```